# Implementing thread-safe HashMaps of very large size

Tags: java, multithreading, opengl, concurrenthashmap

I'm coding a voxel game currently and have stumbled across following problem: While reading my quads from a large (and also volatile!) `ConcurrentHashMap` I get a flickering effect on my screen and on rare occasions my getter function just returns `null`. This `HashMap` uses integers (represented by class `GLTexture`) to store texture IDs as keys and has `ArrayList` objects holding `Quad` objects as values. These lists can reach a total capacity of up to 40000. The GPU handles this fine as I am using very basic (but very effective!) instanced rendering but the chunk generation (which runs on a separate thread, hence the reason for this post) seems to be having problems writing to this map while the renderer is trying to read from it.

```
public class ChunkMeshGenerator {

    private static volatile Map<Chunk, Map<GLTexture, List<Quad>>> quads;
    private static volatile Map<GLTexture, List<Quad>> renderables;

    static {
        quads = new ConcurrentHashMap<Chunk, Map<GLTexture, List<Quad>>>();
        renderables = new ConcurrentHashMap<GLTexture, List<Quad>>();
    }

    public static void genChunk (Chunk chunk) {
        List<Quad> temp = new ArrayList<Quad>();

        Chunk x0 = null;
        Chunk x1 = null;
        Chunk z0 = null;
        Chunk z1 = null;

        synchronized (quads) {
            for (Chunk neighbor : quads.keySet()) {
                if (neighbor.getAbsoluteX() == chunk.getAbsoluteX()-16 && neighbor.getAbsoluteZ() == chunk.getAbsoluteZ()) {
                    x0 = neighbor;
                } else if (neighbor.getAbsoluteX() == chunk.getAbsoluteX()+16 && neighbor.getAbsoluteZ() == chunk.getAbsoluteZ()) {
                    x1 = neighbor;
                } else if (neighbor.getAbsoluteX() == chunk.getAbsoluteX() && neighbor.getAbsoluteZ() == chunk.getAbsoluteZ()-16) {
                    z0 = neighbor;
                } else if (neighbor.getAbsoluteX() == chunk.getAbsoluteX() && neighbor.getAbsoluteZ() == chunk.getAbsoluteZ()+16) {
                    z1 = neighbor;
                }
            }
        }

        for (int x = 0; x < Chunk.CHUNK_SIZE; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < Chunk.CHUNK_HEIGHT; y++) {
                for (int z = 0; z < Chunk.CHUNK_SIZE; z++) {
                    if (chunk.getCube(x, y, z).getType() == BlockType.AIR) continue;
                    if (x == Chunk.CHUNK_SIZE-1) {
                        if (x1 != null && x1.getCube(0, y, z).getType() == BlockType.AIR) {
                            temp.add(chunk.getCube(x, y, z).getFace(Cube.RIGHT));
                        }
                    } else if (chunk.getCube(x+1, y, z).getType() == BlockType.AIR) {
                        temp.add(chunk.getCube(x, y, z).getFace(Cube.RIGHT));
                    }
                    if (x == 0) {
                        if (x0 != null && x0.getCube(Chunk.CHUNK_SIZE-1, y, z).getType() == BlockType.AIR) {
                            temp.add(chunk.getCube(x, y, z).getFace(Cube.LEFT));
                        }
                    } else if (chunk.getCube(x-1, y, z).getType() == BlockType.AIR) {
                        temp.add(chunk.getCube(x, y, z).getFace(Cube.LEFT));
                    }
                    if (y == Chunk.CHUNK_HEIGHT-1) {
                        temp.add(chunk.getCube(x, y, z).getFace(Cube.TOP));
                    } else if (chunk.getCube(x, y+1, z).getType() == BlockType.AIR) {
                        temp.add(chunk.getCube(x, y, z).getFace(Cube.TOP));
                    }
                    if (y != 0 && chunk.getCube(x, y-1, z).getType() == BlockType.AIR) {
                        temp.add(chunk.getCube(x, y, z).getFace(Cube.BOTTOM));
                    }
                    if (z == Chunk.CHUNK_SIZE-1) {
                        if (z1 != null && z1.getCube(x, y, 0).getType() == BlockType.AIR) {
                            temp.add(chunk.getCube(x, y, z).getFace(Cube.BACK));
                        }
                    } else if (chunk.getCube(x, y, z+1).getType() == BlockType.AIR) {
                        temp.add(chunk.getCube(x, y, z).getFace(Cube.BACK));
                    }
                    if (z == 0) {
                        if (z0 != null && z0.getCube(x, y, Chunk.CHUNK_SIZE-1).getType() == BlockType.AIR) {
                            temp.add(chunk.getCube(x, y, z).getFace(Cube.FRONT));
                        }
                    } else if (chunk.getCube(x, y, z-1).getType() == BlockType.AIR) {
                        temp.add(chunk.getCube(x, y, z).getFace(Cube.FRONT));
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        List<Chunk> neighbors = new ArrayList<Chunk>();
        neighbors.add(x0);
        neighbors.add(x1);
        neighbors.add(z0);
        neighbors.add(z1);

        updateNeighbors(chunk, neighbors);

        Map<GLTexture, List<Quad>> map = quads.get(chunk);
        if (map == null) {
            map = new ConcurrentHashMap<GLTexture, List<Quad>>();
            quads.put(chunk, map);
        }

        for (Quad quad : temp) {
            List<Quad> batch = map.get(quad.getTexture());
            if (batch == null) {
                batch = new ArrayList<Quad>();
                map.put(quad.getTexture(), batch);
            }
            batch.add(quad);
        }
        genRenderables();
    }

    private static void updateNeighbors (Chunk chunk, List<Chunk> neighbors) {
        Chunk x0 = neighbors.get(0);
        Chunk x1 = neighbors.get(1);
        Chunk z0 = neighbors.get(2);
        Chunk z1 = neighbors.get(3);

        for (int x = 0; x < Chunk.CHUNK_SIZE; x++) {
            for (int z = 0; z < Chunk.CHUNK_SIZE; z++) {
                for (int y = 0; y < Chunk.CHUNK_HEIGHT; y++) {
                    if (x0 != null &&
                        x0.getCube(Chunk.CHUNK_SIZE-1, y, z).getType() != BlockType.AIR &&
                        chunk.getCube(0, y, z).getType() == BlockType.AIR) {

                        Map<GLTexture, List<Quad>> chunkQuads = quads.get(x0);
                        if (chunkQuads == null) {
                            chunkQuads = new ConcurrentHashMap<GLTexture, List<Quad>>();
                            quads.put(x0, chunkQuads);
                        }

                        Quad face = x0.getCube(Chunk.CHUNK_SIZE-1, y, z).getFace(Cube.RIGHT);
                        List<Quad> batch = chunkQuads.get(face.getTexture());
                        if (batch == null) {
                            batch = new SyncList<Quad>();
                            chunkQuads.put(face.getTexture(), batch);
                        }
                        batch.add(face);
                    }
                    if (x1 != null &&
                        x1.getCube(0, y, z).getType() != BlockType.AIR &&
                        chunk.getCube(Chunk.CHUNK_SIZE-1, y, z).getType() == BlockType.AIR) {

                        Map<GLTexture, List<Quad>> chunkQuads = quads.get(x1);
                        if (chunkQuads == null) {
                            chunkQuads = new ConcurrentHashMap<GLTexture, List<Quad>>();
                            quads.put(x1, chunkQuads);
                        }

                        Quad face = x1.getCube(0, y, z).getFace(Cube.LEFT);
                        List<Quad> batch = chunkQuads.get(face.getTexture());
                        if (batch == null) {
                            batch = new SyncList<Quad>();
                            chunkQuads.put(face.getTexture(), batch);
                        }
                        batch.add(face);
                    }
                    if (z0 != null &&
                        z0.getCube(x, y, Chunk.CHUNK_SIZE-1).getType() != BlockType.AIR &&
                        chunk.getCube(x, y, 0).getType() == BlockType.AIR) {

                        Map<GLTexture, List<Quad>> chunkQuads = quads.get(z0);
                        if (chunkQuads == null) {
                            chunkQuads = new ConcurrentHashMap<GLTexture, List<Quad>>();
                            quads.put(z0, chunkQuads);
                        }

                        Quad face = z0.getCube(x, y, Chunk.CHUNK_SIZE-1).getFace(Cube.BACK);
                        List<Quad> batch = chunkQuads.get(face.getTexture());
                        if (batch == null) {
                            batch = new SyncList<Quad>();
                            chunkQuads.put(face.getTexture(), batch);
                        }
                        batch.add(face);
                    }
                    if (z1 != null &&
                        z1.getCube(x, y, 0).getType() != BlockType.AIR &&
                        chunk.getCube(x, y, Chunk.CHUNK_SIZE-1).getType() == BlockType.AIR) {

                        Map<GLTexture, List<Quad>> chunkQuads = quads.get(z1);
                        if (chunkQuads == null) {
                            chunkQuads = new ConcurrentHashMap<GLTexture, List<Quad>>();
                            quads.put(z1, chunkQuads);
                        }

                        Quad face = z1.getCube(x, y, 0).getFace(Cube.FRONT);
                        List<Quad> batch = chunkQuads.get(face.getTexture());
                        if (batch == null) {
                            batch = new SyncList<Quad>();
                            chunkQuads.put(face.getTexture(), batch);
                        }
                        batch.add(face);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void removeChunk (Chunk chunk) {
        quads.remove(chunk);
        genRenderables();
    }

    public static Map<GLTexture, List<Quad>> getMesh () {
        return renderables;
    }

    private static void genRenderables () {
        renderables.clear();
        for (Chunk chunk : quads.keySet()) {
            for (GLTexture texture : quads.get(chunk).keySet()) {
                renderables.putIfAbsent(texture, new ArrayList<Quad>());
                renderables.get(texture).addAll(quads.get(chunk).get(texture));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The main point here is not the functionality of these methods, but rather the parts where I actually modify the `quads` and `renderables` maps.

As you can see, I write all of the `Quad` objects that I generate to the `quads` map.
The modifying functions always end with a call to `genRenderables()`. This ensures that it takes as little time as possible to write to the map.

I want to make very clear that synchronizing the reading is **NOT** an option, as that would slow down my rendering. I'd rather have the computation time required to go into the chunk generation thread than the rendering thread (in this case the "main" thread).

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

EDIT:
My renderer runs steadily at 60 fps but seems to randomly just freeze up and travel down to 1 fps from time to time, I think these issues are related and any input regarding this is also great.

EDIT:
I just realized that `renderables` is effectively immutable. I clear it and put all of the contents of `quads` into it.

SOLVED:
I implemented a backupMap which I clear after updating `renderables` and add all the current quads. I then wrapped this in a `synchronized` block and did the same for the getter. Flickering is gone as well as weird null pointer exception. Leaving questions open for answers to EDIT #1.

Comment: Interesting, could you elaborate on this? Are you referring to the `genRenderables()` method?

Comment: He might be referring to updateNeighbors and genChunk. The nesting levels do not help too. But I understand games' spatial logic can get cumbersome.

Comment: I don't see a better way to check the surrounding block faces though. I am still going to remove checking of "sandwiched" solid layers which are invisible to improve the time.

Comment: I just edited the `genRenderables()` method. Is this what you were thinking? @GhostCat

Comment: I am talking about the genChunks(). But probably my advice was wrong, as I got lost in the way too complicated source of that method :-)